# Clear recorded CPU call tree

Tags: jprofiler

If I go to `JProfiler->CPU views->Call tree` and press on `Record CPU`, I can detect easily which methods are called when I do a specific action in my application.

If I am doing a different action, I'd like to clear the previous results from the view. Does JProfiles has such a feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just stop and start CPU recording, the results will then be cleared.